# Bootstrap - Main header of site, can't get logos to link

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having an odd issue whereby I have added links to the two logos at the header of my page but when hovering I cannot get them to link off. The links are coded correctly and I can't see any missing div's so at a loss. If I change the CSS class of header to row it works but then that messes up the responsiveness of the page.

Link is [here](http://www.shineinternet.co.uk/demos/header/header.htm): if anyone one could help?

Comment: CSS hack 

`.header {
       position: relative;
       z-index: 1;
    }`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Looks like a float clearing issue to me...

Comment: Apologies, didn't think it would be wise to post all of the html and css as there is quite a lot. Will know for future.

Answer (score 0):

just use clearfix class with header it works.100%

```
<div class="header clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: I have done but says until I get 15 points it won't publicly be displayed :)